# How to control number of allowed checkbox states?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I am using the silverlight 4 toolkit gridcontrol and I'm using auto generated columns.  My boolean field is showing up as a tri-state checkbox (true, false, null).

```
public bool? Enabled { get; set; }
```

How to I force it to use only two states (true/false).  Changing the field type is not an option at this time.

@Bala

[XAML]

```
<sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="liveGrid" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center"
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
ItemsSource="{Binding MyDatasource}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

Just a thought: does a UIHint data annotation exist for this, maybe?

**Possible Solution**

Following @Rick I have a working solution:

[XAML]

```
<sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="liveGrid" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center"
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
AutoGeneratingColumn="viewModel_AutoGeneratingColumn" 
ItemsSource="{Binding MyDatasource}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

[View]

```
 private void viewModel_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if ("Enabled" == e.PropertyName)
        {
            DataGridCheckBoxColumn checkBox = e.Column as DataGridCheckBoxColumn;
            checkBox.IsThreeState = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post your XAML for the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue to use auto-generated columns **and** customize those columns.  Here is an article that describes how to customize auto-generated columns:

- [How to: Customize Auto-Generated Columns in the DataGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

The technique mainly consists of hooking the `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn` event.

If you follow that procedure, all you need to do is find your column (e.g. by property name) and set `IsThreeState` to `false`:

- [DataGridCheckBoxColumn.IsThreeState Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcheckboxcolumn.isthreestate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler solution (using data annotation possibly).  I will start with these links, thanks.

Comment: _By design_ the binding subsystem pays absolutely no attention to metadata about properties like attributes.  The logic is that anything you might want the metadata to do won't handle all cases.  As a result, properties are **just properties** and we have to implement metadata if appropriate to our application.  You **can** use annotations but **you** must make them mean something.